# DB2: How do I display all dates in a range

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I want to expand a range using DB2(on iSeries) query. For example, I have the following value in a table

```
2016-10-01 2016-10-03 600
```

I want the output as

```
2016-10-01 200 
2016-10-02 200
2016-10-03 200
```

I tried but I am not able to develop the query. It should be somewhere in similar lines as below.

---

Table (MYTABLE) has two columns. Below is snapshot

```
START_DT    END_DT    
2016-01-01  2016-01-03
```

On this query

```
with temp1 as                                 
(                                             
  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, start_dt as dt     
  FROM mytable                                
    UNION                                     

  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, dt + 1 day as dt   
  FROM temp1                                  
  WHERE dt < end_dt                           
)                                             
SELECT dt                                     
FROM temp1
```

I am getting the error "Column list not valid for table".

I tried this as well

```
with temp1 (start_dt, end_dt, dt) as             
(                                                
  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, start_dt as dt        
  FROM mytable                                   
    UNION                                        

  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, dt + 1 day as dt      
  FROM temp1                                     
  WHERE dt < end_dt                              
)                                                
SELECT dt                                        
FROM temp1
```

This is throwing error "Keyword not allowed in recursive common table expression TEMP1."

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @mustaccio I have edited the question

Comment: you say "I have the following value in a table" but you don't show the column names.  Makes it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: so you have 3 columns -- start_dt, end_dt and value and you want to divide value even between rows with the dates from start to end?

Comment: well I thought it was obvious that 2016-10-01 is from date and 2016-10-03 is to date. I should have put it more clear. I am not worried about the amount (600 in the example) right now. If somehow I am able to display all dates between from date and to date, it will solve the basic problem

Comment: it was not obvious.

Comment: So, that query of yours, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @mustaccio -- I think it would be better to ask "What is right with it?" to which I'd say "nothing"

Comment: @Hogan Go easy on me :) I am stuck on this from very long

Comment: @vijayksingh.vj - I went easy on you I gave you a solution.  Seems better than easy actually -- seems darn nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test -- this works on 9.7

```
with table1(start_dt,end_dt, amount) as
(
  values (timestamp('2017-01-01'), timestamp('2017-01-03'), 600)

), this_is_not_a_reserved_word (start_dt, end_dt, d, amount) as
(
  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, start_dt as d,
         amount/ (timestampdiff(16,end_dt-start_dt)+1) as amount
  FROM table1
--  WHERE tab_id_id = 518621     

    UNION ALL

  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, d + 1 day , amount
  FROM this_is_not_a_reserved_word
  WHERE d < end_dt
)
SELECT d, amount
FROM this_is_not_a_reserved_word
```

---

*original answer*

Here you go:

```
with this_is_not_a_reserved_word as
(
  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, start_dt as dt, amount/timestampdiff(16,start_dt-end_dt) as amount
  FROM table1
  WHERE tab_id_id = 518621     

    UNION 

  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, dt + 1 day as dt, amount
  FROM this_is_not_a_reserved_word
  WHERE dt < end_dt
)
SELECT dt, amount
FROM this_is_not_a_reserved_word
```

If start_dt and end_dt are type date and not timestamp use:

```
amount/timestampdiff(16,timestamp(start_dt)-timestamp(end_dt)) as amount
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this. I am using DB2 on iseries. The above doesnt work. Without providing the column list in "Working" table I get the error "Column list not valid for table" and after providing the column list I get the error "Keyword not allowed in recursive common table expression WORKING." which I was getting with the code in question too.

Comment: so change the random name "working" to something else like this_is_not_a_reserved_word

Comment: i tried that. In my query i use Temp1 instead of "Working".The error is not specific to the word.

Comment: @vijayksingh.vj - I had the syntax for timestampdiff wrong.

Comment: @vijayksingh.vj -- see my working example code -- remember you want the query before the UNION to return only one row -- or you will get an error.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @vijayksingh.vj -- note my working solution uses `UNION ALL` not `UNION`

Comment: Works now. Thank you so much! Both for knowledge and patience

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with temp1  ( start_dt,   end_dt, DateCalc, num)  as                             
(                                             
  SELECT start_dt, end_dt, start_dt, 0  
  FROM  yourtable                                
  UNION  all                                   
  SELECT start_dt, end_dt,  DateCalc+ 1 day, num +1
  FROM temp1                                  
  WHERE DateCalc < end_dt                           
)                                             
SELECT DateCalc                                     
FROM temp1
```